# I have an array in python and I want to convert it to 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, object, types, integer

I want to convert this array:

```
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)],
      dtype=object)
```

to simple 1d array like this:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: What is the issue? How did you even end up with that first array?

Comment: I need a permutation of first array's elements, but the first array has just one element and it's type is 'object'.
So, the result of permutation is not proper.

Comment: Right, but how are these arrays built, why do you end up with this result?

Comment: This array is output of Louvain Community detection function.
(Actually one part of that function)

Comment: Is it user defined?

Comment: Yes! and the problem is solved. jmkjaer's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552469/jmkjaer) answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to wrap the element in the first array in an `np.array`, and pass `dtype=np.int64`:

```py
a = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.int64)], dtype=object)
b = np.array(a[0], dtype=np.int64)
```